# Haskell - List of Characters recursion

Tags: haskell

I am currently doing an assignment in Haskell, which i need some help with.

The basic function is to find the number of vowels in a string.

This is my code so far:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Tuple

vowels :: [Char]
vowels = "aeiou"    --List of vowel characters

getLetterCount :: Char -> String -> Int
getLetterCount c s = length (filter (\x -> x == c) s)

getLetterTuple :: Char -> String -> (Char, Int)
getLetterTuple c s = (c, (getLetterCount c s))

getVowelCount :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
getVowelCount s = [ getLetterTuple (head vowels) s ]

main = do
 putStrLn $ show $ getVowelCount "many vowels in this sentence"
```

The which gives this output:

```
[('a',1)]
```

However, the output needs to be this:

```
[('a',1),('e',4),('i',2),('o',1),('u',0)]
```

I can't seem to loop through each item in the

```
vowels :: [Char]
vowels = "aeiou"
```

list.

Does anyone know how I might do this??

Any help would be really appreciated, Thanks

Comment: you're nearly there, but by using `head` you're deliberately restricting yourself to just the first vowel. What you want here is the `map` function.

Comment: yeah i've been trying to fiddle around with map but cant seem to get that to work, any tips?

Comment: Hint: use `flip` and `map` functions

Comment: Instead of evaluating `getVowelCount` for only `head vowels` you might want to look at [list comprehensions](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension) so you can evaluate it for each vowel.

Comment: yes, it's actually a little bit more involved than I initially thought, because the arguments to your `getLetterTuple` function are not in the most natural order. (Order of arguments counts for more in Haskell than it does in most other languages.) But this is what `flip` is for. `map (flip getLetterTuple s) vowels` should do it. (Would have just been `map (getLetterTuple s) vowels` if you'd swapped the order of arguments in `getLetterTuple` yourself.) Have a look at what currying is as well, this will help you understand what's happening.

Comment: thank you robin that worked, im still a bit confused about the flip part? how does that make a difference? (im still very new to haskell haha) and ok i'll look into it, i think it was covered briefly in a lecture so i'll give it a read and try to understand

Comment: I would offer some different suggestions: never use list comprehensions ever, write a working solution using recursion, only then refine: factor out the recursion if appropriate (using a higher order function), rearrange function arguments to avoid lambdas, etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to expand upon the answer I already gave in the comments, since I was asked to explain a little more:

```
getVowelCount s = map (flip getLetterTuple s) vowels
```

First, let's look at the definition of `flip` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#flip):

```
flip                    :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f x y              =  f y x
```

As its name suggests, this flips the arguments of a function of 2 arguments. (More generally, because of currying, it flips the first 2 arguments of any function which takes 2 or more.) So, where `getLetterTuple` has type `Char -> String -> (Char, Int)`,  `flip getLetterTuple` has type `String -> Char -> (Char, Int)`. The order is important because this can be rewritten as `String -> (Char -> (Char, Int))`. This means that, given a string (your `s` here), `flip getLetterTuple` gives a function from a `Char` to a pair `(Char, Int)`.

So `flip getLetterTuple s` (which we get from "partially applying" `flip getLetterTuple`) is a function which, given a character, yields a pair consisting of that letter and the number of times it occurs in `s`. Now if we `map` that over `vowels` - which is just a list of characters (`"aeiou"` is syntactic sugar for the list `['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']`), we get the result you want. [If you're not too familiar with `map`, it takes a function and a list and applies the function to every element of the list, resulting in a new list.]

I hope this explains what is going on, although you might have to reread some of it a few times to understand. Feel free to ask if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Tuple

vowels :: [Char]
vowels = "aeiou"    --List of vowel characters

getLetterCount :: Char -> String -> Int
getLetterCount c s = length (filter (\x -> x == c) s)

getLetterTuple :: String -> Char -> (Char, Int)
getLetterTuple s c = (c, (getLetterCount c s))

getVowelCount :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
getVowelCount s = map (getLetterTuple s) vowels

main = do
 putStrLn $ show $ getVowelCount "many vowels in this sentence"
```

With this you avoid the flip